# HTML5 Playlist plays 2 videos, How about 4 or 5?

Tags: javascript, html5-video

I'm able to get two videos to play sequentially, (and without pause!) with this code from Apple, (see section 2-4)...

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript/ControllingMediaWithJavaScript.html

...Yet completely lost as to how to play a 3rd or 5th video.  Trouble is I'm a Javascript noob :-(, so if you figure this out please share as much of your code as possible.

Answer (score 5):

The first video's ended => Start second video
The second video's ended => Start third video
The third video's ended => Start fourth video
The fourth video's ended => Start first video

It's just redefining the `ended` event handler nonstop...
You could also use a variable starting at 0.  increment it each time and set SRC to i%video_count

```
var i = 0;
var sources = ["http://www.a.com/blargh.m4v", "http://www.b.com/blargh.m4v"];
videoElement.addEventListener('ended', function(){
   videoElement.src = sources[(++i)%sources.length];
   videoElement.load();
   videoElement.play();
}, false);
```

...The above code assumes the video is already playing onload, like your example