# trying to set data in html5 video player with database object

Tags: asp.net, html

Okay guys so i am trying to set the data like this.

```
<object width="510" height="315"
   data="<%#Eval("Trailer")%>">
 </object>
```

and this is the link i am supose to get from the database: https://www.youtube.com/v/aO-1ZBsT224

i have also tried this with the iframe and embed, i can't seem to get it to work unless i do i like this

```
<object width="510" height="315"
   data="https://www.youtube.com/v/aO-1ZBsT224">
 </object>
```

but i have a uniq link on every object so i wont work if i do it this way.

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following.  An HTML5 video player would use the <video> tag, not the <object> tag.  It looks more like you're trying to embed a YouTube video.

Comment: i have also tried that Dan. But for some reason i will not work? now i have gotten it to work with this link. https://www.youtube.com/v/63BJB9bECB0 but for some reason i will not work with these two https://www.youtube.com/v/aO-1ZBsT224 https://www.youtube.com/v/QkkoHAzjnUs

Comment: only with one of the links? can seem to figure out why. I dont make sense to me.

Comment: What is the output from <%#Eval("Trailer")%>?

Comment: the output is the links that i have posted above. That is why i dont understand it wont work

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are having issues playing videos one after the other. If so, take a look at this: http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/How-to-play-multiple-videos-in-a-loop-using-HTML5-and-JavaScript-1799.php

While searching for an answer to your question I came across these two issues and one article. Hope they might help you:

- [How to Embed Youtube Videos into HTML5 <video> Tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13177359/how-to-embed-youtube-videos-into-html5-video-tag)
- [HTML5 Playlist plays 2 videos, How about 4 or 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945580/html5-playlist-plays-2-videos-how-about-4-or-5)
- http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/client/how-to-embed-video-using-html5.html#fbid=LGEMKw9Trim